.locale in freemarker template is returning old ISO 639 language codes for Hebrew/Indonesian
.locale in freemarker template is returning old ISO 639 code for Hebrew language  i.e."iw_IL" . But I require the latest code "he_IL". can we convert the old ISO to the latest one. Need a way to get the latest one without manually writing the conditions to convert.

It's an issue with the localization data Java is shipped with, and not with FreeMarker. Try to upgrade to Java 17!
For me, on Windows and Oracle Java, System.out.println(new Locale("he", "IL")) prints he_IL on Java 17, but iw_IL on Java 16 and 11.
